# Populate a flat array of incremented integers with a limit and constraints to keep/ignore some values

Tags: php, arrays, range, slice, populate

I have array structure for `13` with `range (1,13)`;
it something like

```
array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13);

$slice = 2;
$ignore = 3;
```

I want array structure like `array(3,4,5,8,9,10,13);`

I tried with `array_slice()` function but I couldn't offset the value sequentially.

`array_slice($array,2,13,true);`
is there a way to ignore the next `3` values and add slice to the next second until last array, any native function or key will be great.

Comment: Do you need to retain the indexes of the original array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prioritize performance, minimize loops/cycles and function calls.  Using a single `for` loop and no function calls is probably the most efficient approach but won't win any awards for being beautiful/intuitive code. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/nFvQT))

```
$limit = 13;
$skip = 2;
$keep = 3;
$result = [];
for (
    $x = 1 + $skip, $k = 1;
    $x <= $limit;
    $x += ($k++ % $keep ? 1 : 1 + $skip)
) {
    $result[] = $x;
}
var_export($result);
```

---

Writing conditional `continue` statements means wasted/fruitless iterations -- ergo poorer performance, but maybe this is more comprehensible. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/IAqm3))

```
$limit = 13;
$skip = 2;
$keep = 3;
$result = [];

for ($x = 1; $x <= $limit; ++$x) {
    if (($x - 1) % ($skip + $keep) < $skip) {
        continue;
    }
    $result[] = $x;
}
var_export($result);
```

---

A recursive approach can be written without declaring any variables beyond the callback signature. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/7P41g))

```
function slice_recursive(array $array, int $skip, int $keep): array
{
    if (!$array) {
        return $array;
    }
    return array_merge(
        array_slice(
            array_splice($array, 0, $skip + $keep),
            $skip
        ),
        slice_recursive($array, $skip, $keep)
    );
}

var_export(
    slice_recursive(range(1, 13), 2, 3)
);
```

---

A similar, non-recursive approach can be written too.  In this script, the consumption of the input array has the effect of actually reducing the original array to an empty array. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/IQvEr))

```
$limit = 13;
$skip = 2;
$keep = 3;
$result = [];

$array = range(1, 13);
while ($array) {
    array_push(
        $result,
        ...array_slice(
            array_splice($array, 0, $skip + $keep),
            $skip
        )
    );
}
var_export($result);
```

---

There will be several more ways to satisfy the task requirements.  Usually microoptimized performance is an unnecessary pursuit -- choose the script that you understand and can maintain.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a function that will recursively perform an "asymmetric" slicing of an array of `n` length:

```php
function slice_asym(array $head, $exclude, $include)
{
    $keep = array_slice($head, $exclude, $include);
    $tail = array_slice($head, $exclude + $include);

    return $tail ? array_merge($keep, slice_asym($tail, $exclude, $include)) 
                 : $keep;
}
```

Recursion requires a *base case* where recursion stops and all scopes unwind and return. In our case, we want to stop when the `tail` contains no more elements.

`array_slice()` always returns an array - if there are no elements to return for its given offset, `array_slice()` returns an empty array. So, for each recursion, we want to:

1. Slice out the element(s) that we want to `$keep`
2. Create a `$tail` - this is a subset of the array that excludes the elements that we both want to ignore and keep in the current scope (`$exclude + $include`).
3. If the `$tail` is not empty, create a new level of recursion. Otherwise stop recursion and merge all current `$keep` elements with the result of the next level of recursion.

In pseudocode, this looks something like:

```
# step 1: first recursion
head = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13]
keep =     [3,4,5]
tail =           [6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13] # tail not empty

# step 2: second recursion
head =           [6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13] 
keep =               [8,9,10]
tail =                      [11,12,13] # tail not empty

# step 3: third recursion
head =                      [11,12,13] 
keep =                            [13]
tail =                              [] # tail empty: base case met!

# return and merge `keep` elements
[3,4,5] + [8, 9, 10] + [13] -> [3,4,5,8,9,10,13]
```

As per your example, the following invocation:

```php
$range  = range(1, 13); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
$sliced = slice_asym($range, 2, 3);

print_r($sliced);
```

Yields:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 4
    [2] => 5
    [3] => 8
    [4] => 9
    [5] => 10
    [6] => 13
)
```

**Edit**

If you are using PHP version 5.5 or above, this is also a good use case for a [generator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.generators.overview.php).

These are useful because:

> A generator allows you to write code that uses foreach to iterate over a set of data without needing to build an array in memory, which may cause you to exceed a memory limit, or require a considerable amount of processing time to generate.

So, you would not have to pre-create an array of sequential values:

> Instead, you can write a generator function, which is the same as a normal function, except that instead of returning once, a generator can yield as many times as it needs to in order to provide the values to be iterated over.

We could implement a generator for your use case like so:

```
/**
 * 
 * @param  int $limit  
 * @param  int $exclude
 * @param  int $include
 * @return int
 */
function xrange_asym($limit, $exclude, $include) {

    if ($limit < 0 || $exclude < 0 || $include < 0) {
        throw new UnexpectedValueException(
            '`xrange_asym` does not accept negative values');
    }

    $seq = 1;
    $min = $exclude;
    $max = $exclude + $include;

    while ($seq <= $limit) {

        if ($seq > $min && $seq <= $max) {
            yield $seq;
        }

        if ($seq === $max) {
            $min = $exclude + $max;
            $max = $exclude + $include + $max;
        }

        $seq = $seq + 1;
    }
}
```

and use it, like so:

```
foreach (xrange_asym(13, 2, 3) as $number) {
    echo $number . ', '; //  3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10, 13
}
```

Or use `iterator_to_array()` to generate the whole range as an array:

```
print_r(iterator_to_array(xrange_asym(13, 2, 3)));
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Nice. A very professional, educationally explained answer containing the techniques of recursion and implementing a generator.

Comment: Thanks @mickmackusa :) I totally forgot about this answer, fun to read it again.

Answer (score 1):

Using `array_merge()`, function one could join two array slice.  This will return a new array.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

```
$slice = 2;
$ignore = 3;
$a = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13);
$a = array_merge(
         array_slice($a, $slice, $ignore),
         array_merge(
             array_slice($a, 2 * $slice + $ignore, 3),
             array_slice($a, 3 * $slice + 2 * $ignore)
         )
     );
var_dump($a);
```

Comment: Appreciate your response, array(9) { [0]=> int(3) [1]=> int(4) [2]=> int(5) [3]=> int(8) [4]=> int(9) [5]=> int(10) [6]=> int(11) [7]=> int(12) [8]=> int(13) }  but it returns 11,12 too?

Comment: This will do the job. Sorry i haven't notice that one.     `$a = array_merge(array_slice($a, 2,3),array_merge(array_slice($a, 7,3),  array_slice($a, 12)));`

Comment: nope i want it should be dynamic based on variable value as i set above

Comment: I have changed it into dynamic. you can specify   `$slice`   and   `$ignore`   . :)

Comment: With hardcode merge and slice calls, this script has nearly no dynamic benefit.  If the developer was able to hardcode these parts, they might as well just hardcode the exact output array with no function calls at all.